# When can we find different axiomatizations for theories with the same models?

Tags: logic, model-theory, universal-algebra

The theory of groups can be axiomatized in the usual way, saying there must exist inverses, a unit element, and associativity must hold, or it could be written down in a "single axiom" as done [here](https://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/tech_reports/reports/P270.pdf). This can also be done for [Boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_axioms_for_Boolean_algebra), [ortholattices](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emccune/prover9/examples/2009-02A/olsax/index.html), and some other algebraic structures. It is worth noting that these axiomatizations seem to be in a language with just one binary relation, or just a binary relation and maybe a constant. Furthermore, the axioms themselves seem to be $\Pi^0_1$.

I should say, I'd describe the axiomatizations I am thinking about as "nontrivial" where a "trivial" example would be to just take the conjunction of the usual axioms for any given theory. Also, the simpler the language (so the signature), the more interesting I would find the axiomatization (e.g. a single axiom in a language with no constants is more interesting than one in a language with one constant). Also the simpler the axiomatization (e.g. no $\Sigma^0_2$ (or above) formulas), the more interesting.

So now I ask, when can we find alternate/alternate and interesting axiomatizations for theories that have the same models (so could be thought of as similar/the same theory)?

Comment: I just had a skim of the paper, and I thought it was extremely interesting!

Comment: I am glad you think so - I find it extremely cool too

Answer (score 2):

One interesting example of this phenomenon, while far from the examples you give, is when we have an **infinite-to-finite** improvement: an infinite set of axioms $T$ which turns out to be finitely axiomatizable.

The two most common infinite systems of axioms are probably (modulo small variations) $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\mathsf{PA}$. It is known that neither theory is finitely axiomatizable, since in each case the theory proves the consistency of each of its finite subtheories - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle#In_ZFC) for the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ case. However, they do have *fragments* which still are most obviously infinitely axiomatized but now do turn out to have finite axiomatizations, specifically by restricting the relevant schemes (separation/replacement and induction, respectively) to a fixed level of an appropriate hierarchy (the [Levy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy) and [arithmetical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) hierarchies, respectively). Finite axiomatizability of these "bounded" fragments follows from the existence of **universal** formulas in each class, like how the halting problem is a *complete* c.e. set. This "universal formula" trick gives finite axiomatizability for a lot of other theories too, e.g. each of the "Big Five" in reverse mathematics.

We even have a natural(ish) example which is *not* simply a fragment of a better-behaved theory; specifically, Quine's alternate set theory [New Foundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#Finite_axiomatizability) and many of its variants.